# Change Name of uploaded files in powermail formular on typo3

Tags: pdf, upload, typo3, suffix, powermail

i hope someone could help me with my question.

I have on a typo3 site a form for applications. On this form you have the ability to upload different documents for curriculum vitae and certificates.
This form is created with a powermail plugin.

The email, generatedfrom the form, should pass a gateway and automatically inserted into a database. And I got some problems with the files.

1. The files should not have the same name. If a candidate load up files with the same name the gateway can not see, which one is for vitae and which for certificate.
2. Typo3 put every file in one folder and put a suffix on it when there is already a file with that name. But this suffix is not reportet to the email. So when i got the email it says for example the file for certificate is "certificate.pdf" but the real name of the file is certificate_2.pdf

I think the best way to solve the problems is, to give the files an unique praefix. So the candidade upload a file xxx.pdf for certificate, but the form change the name to certificate_xxx.pdf before it was send.

Or the suffix would be also displayed in the email and not only in the file name.

I hope that is understandable (sorry, english is not my native) and someone could help me.

Greetings
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

If you try to upload two files with the same name and powermail can not handle it, this is a bug. In this case: Pls report to github!

But, powermail can randomize filenames if this is an option to you:
https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/setup.typoscript#L545

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. powermail has no problems to handle with 2 files and the same name. The problem cames that the software which get the information from the generated email cant handle it. So i need to have different names. I tried tu use randomize filenames. I dont find it in the constants.txt so i wrote this into my setup.txt

Comment: # File upload settings
    file {
     folder = {$plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.uploadFolder}
     size = {$plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.uploadSize}
     extension = {$plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.uploadFileExtensions}
                                        randomizeFileName = {1}
    }

Comment: Please remove the curly brackets on the last setting: `randomizeFileName = 1` and try again.

Comment: Thansk for the anwer. but it still not work. :( I made a new ask about this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340803/how-to-activate-randomized-filenames-in-powermail

Comment: Just add a new line to constants:
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.randomizeFileName=1

Comment: Thank you, i will respons in the other ticket, cause i think this are to different things to talk about.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. I make some screenshots from both files. constants.txt: imgur.com/MPWumvy.jpg , setup.txt: imgur.com/jZhbu0J.jpg , email result: imgur.com/8z2kuVG.jpg Maybe its wrong path? both files are located at: typo3cms/sitename/typo3conf/ext/powermail/Configuration/Typo‌​Script/Main/constant‌​s.txt

Comment: In the constants.txt there are values before each "main"-value, something like "# cat=powermail_additional//0800; type=boolean; label= Show only filled values: If the user submits a form, even not filled values are viewable. If you only want to show labels with filled values, use this setting" Maybe that is missing for this task?

Comment: If it isn't working after you've added the line to constants, there must be a failure in your TypoScript configuration. Powermail 2.2 or newer supports randomizing filenames. Pls check with the object browser if the value is set correct: https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/attachment/1406673/zkglqvxd9s1dr6vy28wr/262407-Z8KQ3tNZ5O7QuM6L/screen.png