# How to activate randomized filenames in powermail

Tags: random, typo3, powermail

i have a form where user could upload files. There are 3 files they could upload and each of them need to have an unique name. So even the person upload the same file everytime i neet different names for it in the email, i get from the form.

So i try to use randomizeFileName.
https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/setup.txt#L538

Cause i dont have the randomizeFilename in my constants.txt it try to enter it in my setup.txt with a real value.

```
# File upload settings
file {
  folder = {$plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.uploadFolder}
  size = {$plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.uploadSize}
  extension = {$plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.uploadFileExtensions}
  randomizeFileName = 1
}
```

But sadly that dont work. The file issues-1.pdf still has the same name (+ a suffix cause i tried it a lot time )

[image]

I hope someone can help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: See my answer in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338988/change-name-of-uploaded-files-in-powermail-formular-on-typo3

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. I tried it as you wrote in the other ticket. it still dont work. I make some screenshots from both files. constants.txt: https://imgur.com/MPWumvy.jpg , setup.txt: https://imgur.com/jZhbu0J.jpg , email result: https://imgur.com/8z2kuVG.jpg Maybe its wrong path? both files are located at: typo3cms/sitename/typo3conf/ext/powermail/Configuration/TypoScript/Main/constants.txt

Comment: In the constants.txt there are values before each "main"-value, something like "# cat=powermail_additional//0800; type=boolean; label= Show only filled values: If the user submits a form, even not filled values are viewable. If you only want to show labels with filled values, use this setting" Maybe that is missing for this task?

Comment: "Cause i dont have the randomizeFilename in my constants.txt" just add it as `plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.randomizeFileName = 1` to your constants in the Typoscript Template!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the setup file included in the extension, the correct syntax for Powermail 7.x would be:

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.randomizeFileName = 1
```

`randomizeFileName = 1` is the default value in Powermail 7.x!

You have to set this over Typoscript Constant, not in Typoscript Setup:

In Typoscript Setup this may work. (Not Tested)

```
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.Pi2.misc.file.randomizeFileName = 1
```

Read the source code to see more:
https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Configuration/TypoScript/Powermail_Frontend/setup.txt

Or the documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/stable/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/MainTypoScript/Index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Sadly the change does not help or i do it wrong.